# Aquery : network error -101 with https

Tags: android, https, aquery

Android Aquery is giving Ajaxstatus code as -101 with the message 'network error' while making a https request in some particular version of devices(below 7.0).
With http it's working fine in all versions. With https it's not working the device versions below 7.0.

Any working solutions?

Comment: net error 101(connection reset)

Comment: @HajAli it is '-101' : Aquery's Ajaxstatus code